# Alignment weirdness in relativelayout with a background image

Tags: android, textview, alignment, patch, android-relativelayout

I have a 9 patch png in a RelativeLayout and everything looks great! However, when i create a textView in the RL, the textView is not at the top of the parent... I also tested this on the phone, same result... why does it do this?

Thanks for your assistance!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testLL"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/contentbox">

        <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: RelativeView]
[image: TextView]

Comment: Can you post the images themselves that you are using?

Comment: Could you possibly illustrate / tell where you expect/want the textview to show up?  In that grey area?  If that isn't the "stretchy" part of the 9patch, it adds that amount of pixels to the padding automatically.

Comment: It is possibly because of the defined content area of 9-patch image that you used in the relative layout.

Comment: Try without 9-patch background, what do you get?

Comment: @Maximus here's the 9patch image I'm using.. http://img808.imageshack.us/img808/6325/contentbox9.png  and yes, I exptected the text to show in the grey area. How do you suggest I do the 9patch? I read Eric's message, but I don't want to have to specify padding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking up how 9patches are rendered, it basically turns the non-stretchable areas into default layout padding.  This is to facilitate easy entry of stuff into the target (stretchable) area, without having to go in and define paddings manually.  By assigning a 9patch, you are using it's padding.  It assigns paddings to top left right and bottom based on how many px the 9patch has until it reaches the stretchable center.

You may try doing something like android:paddingTop="-50px" in your textView and see what happens.  I haven't tested this, so I'd be interested to see how it turns out.

Edit to your comment with pic:  Since your 9patch's top stretchy region doesnt start for about 90 px, its automatically going to pad the first element 90 px down, to place it within the "stretchy target" region.  Try my above suggestion to see how it works, I'm pretty interested to see how it turns out.  I don't have my IDE accessible from my Mobile, otherwise I'd test it for you  ;)

Edit:  I apologize, I've been saying "padding" instead of margin.  But the theory is the same.  Not modifying the above for permanent documentation of my idiocy.

Comment: So I should edit the margins negatively? What about just editng the 9 patch?

Comment: Did you try it with layout_marginTop instead of paddingTop?  I had the derp in my brain when i was typing that previously.   If that doesn't work, I don't know.  The spirit of a 9patch is to encapsulate, not to let things draw in it's defined borders, like you are attempting

Comment: AAACTUALLY, after further playing around and googling, your answer is correct, but backwards (in a way). You don't set the padding negatively on the TextView, you just set the RelativeLayout that has the 9patch png to 0. Now my text is directly in the corner where it should be so I can start organizing it. Thanks for your help! Check mark for you!

Comment: OOps, I didn't refresh your comment...but you were on the right track to begin with :P